# access runtime-compiled application.js on tddium

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets

locally my application.js is fine. But when running my tests on tddium, the javascript does not work. After dumping page.error_messages (from capybara-webkit) at the failing spec, i see:

```
{:line_number=>26654, :message=>"SyntaxError: Parse error", :source=>"http://127.0.0.1:35634/assets/application.js"}
```

So, because the file is compiled (but not compressed) at runtime on tddium. I have to get it to see whats going wrong there.

When its compiled at runtime, i think it does not reside in public/assets but in cache, right? How can i access this file?

Thanks for help - cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

And see if you get any errors.

Usually you'll get an error message telling you what file and line number the error is at.

The error message says that you have an error on line 26654 in the application.js file. If you don't get any error messages during precompiling, you can take a look at the application.js, line 26654 in the public/assets directory after precompiling is done.

Comment: I did that, but there is no syntax error :( So somethings is different on tddium and i need to get the file that is compiled on tddium i think.

Comment: Have you looked at line 26654 in the application.js file after precompiling locally.

Answer (score 0):

(Tddium co-founder, here.)

It's possible (but not yet documented) to attach arbitrary build artifacts to a Tddium build so that they're included in the list of files at the end of the build report page.

Take a look at:

https://github.com/solanolabs/tddium/blob/master/lib/tddium/agent/tddium.rb#L66

You can use that with a post-build task to save whatever you need.

http://docs.tddium.com/getting-started/post-build-tasks

Contact us at support@tddium.com if you need specific help.